# Trouble while sending large amounts of mail via Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I'm using Outlook REST API to send mail.
When I try to send 7000 emails via Outlook api, there are 78 mails cannot be sent and moved to draft folder. I wonder if it is default action of outlook api or it is an error ?
Thank you !

Comment: In what time period did you try to send 7,000 mails?  We do have restrictions on max # of mails that can be sent out from by a single mailbox.

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT I sent 70 times, each time has 100 mails. (7000 requests send mail). Can you tell me more about that restriction?

Comment: What was the time period during which you sent those mails.  In parallel, I will let you know the limit we place on # of mails sent out from a single mailbox.

Comment: I am asking how fast you are sending the messages.  You may be running into message rate limits.  See the answer that I just posted and let me know if I am missing anything.  Thanks,

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT Thanks bro, I read the document and saw this : `For users submitting via any other mechanism, the messages are accepted, but Exchange Online will queue them at the server and throttle the rate of delivery.`. Our customer tell me, some mails not be sent success will be moved to Draft folder. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into message send limits as documented here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx#RecipientLimits If you believe you are within the documented limits, let me know and we can investigate further.

Comment: Thank you ! I will check it again then let you know soon.